# Save output of Con statement to different folder

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, python-2.7

I have a folder of shapefiles that I want to convert to rasters and then apply a Con statement to them. I set my workspace to where the shapefiles are and do Point to Raster conversion and Con with the following code:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#Set workspace to Max Temps folder and allow for overwrite
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\DailyMax2015"
outputFolder = r"C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\RasterCon2015"

#Get Max Temp shapefiles and convert them to Raster
shpFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")
for shpFile in shpFileList:
    shpFileName = os.path.splitext (shpFile)[0]
    rastFile = shpFileName + ".tif"
    arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(shpFile, "Max_2015", rastFile, "MOST_FREQUENT", "", 0.05)

#Get raster files and run through Raster Calculator to see if Max threshold has been met
rastFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.tif")
for rastFile in rastFileList:
    rastFileName = os.path.splitext (rastFile) [0]
    MaxRstIn = Raster(rastFile)
    MaxRstOut = Con(MaxRstIn, 1, 0, "VALUE <=85")
    MaxRstOut.save("Con" + rastFile)
```

How do I save the output rasters of the Con function in a separate folder? I have specified an output folder but am stuck on pointing my Con files to go here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never actually creating the complete output path to save the raster to. You need to use the variable you create initially `outputFolder` with `os.path.join` and the file name that you want and feed that into the `.save()` method. Like this:

```
output_raster_path = os.path.join(outputFolder, "Con" + rastFile)
MaxRstOut.save(output_raster_path)
```